# Why can't I move a window to the top left corner with wmctrl in Unity?

Tags: command-line, unity, window-manager, xdotool, wmctrl

I've been playing around with `wmctrl` to take more control of my windows.
I've encountered a weird behaviour where Unity reserves double the space.
See this screen shot:

[image]

I opened the terminal and moved the window using the top command. It should be at the top left corner (X=0 Y=0). But for some reason there is some margin between the terminal and the Unity bars.

If I understand the man pages correctly it might have something to do with the *WA: 65,24*.

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Probably not the answer you were looking for:*

#### Issues with the combination of Unity and `wmctrl`

The combination of Unity and `wmctrl` unfortunately has a few peculiarities, of which the behaviour you describe is one.

#### Looking at your output

- The `65,24` you mention, are the *width* of the Unity Launcher and the *height* of your panel.
- In the line:

  ```
  0x03400005  0 0   24    65   1111  janw_VirtualBox unity-launcher
  ```

  in the output of `wmctrl -lG`, you can see that the Launcher is *positioned* at `x=0, y=24`, while the size of the launcher is `65 x 1111`. (`1111` is the height of your screen minus the height of your panel)

Strictly, the command to place the active window in the top left corner should therefore be:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,65,24,1500,550
```

and not:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,1500,550
```

However, this will not solve the issue, it simply is a bug. There still will be the marge you describe. The same will happen by the way when using `xdotool` (not installed by default):

```
xdotool windowmove "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"  65 24
```

or

```
xdotool windowmove "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"  0 0
```

#### Reading the output of `wmctrl -dG`

Looking at the `1792x1111` in `WA: 65,24 1792x1111`, you can see that you have a monitor resolution of `1857` (`65`+`1792`) x `1135` (`1111`+`24`). 
*In this case*, it matches exactly the values in `DG: 1857x1135`, since you only have one viewport (workspace): `DG` stands for the *total* size of your desktop (all viewports).

#### Summarizing

Both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` work fine if you set a window *maximized*. The effect you describe will not occur. *Moving* or *resizing* windows will however leave a few pixels from both the launcher and the panel, as described in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/565087/72216): 
*"The window to be moved/re-sized needs to be at least a few px from both the Unity launcher and the top panel."*

Apart from what you describe, another issue you will run into if you start playing around with `wmctrl` and `Unity` is the *deviation*, as described in [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576604/what-causes-the-deviation-in-the-wmctrl-window-move-command).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not what I was hoping, but I kinda expected something like this. Mint+cinnamon doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Bug report for Unity: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1452405