# Command to span window across multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, compiz, window-manager, wmctrl

Trying to create a shortcut to take the active window and display it across two displays.  Using the following only maximizes it on a single monitor:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,1800,2300
```

Comment: This seems to be the fault of Compiz/Unity. It works nicely with LXDE. I as well am looking for a solution that prevents Compiz/Unity from "clipping" the window dimensions to one screen. The solution suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73573#answer-94192) isn't an option.

Comment: So essentially you want the window to stretch from monitor A to monitor B ? Just trying to make sure I understand correctly what you want. I can make a script that does it for you, should be fairly easy, and that can be bound to shortcut

Comment: OK, maybe not so easy . . .

Comment: duplicate off - http://askubuntu.com/questions/73573/how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Amias  As was said by ThomasW in the first comment, that post is not an answer.  The bounty seeks alternative solution

Comment: It seems [this can not be solved with wmctrl](http://askubuntu.com/questions/739155#739259) as Compiz/Unity interfere with it. If there is a solution, I expect it can only be Compiz based, but so far I did not find a plugin that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

**Dual Monitors in Unity**:

Hold your move-window modifier (it is <kbd>alt</kbd> by default) and drag the window from within the window's chrome (body) as opposed to the title bar (using your mouse).

Comment: I think the OP knows very well how to resize windows manually. This is about creating a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the DF taskbar and select Settings.

Click on the Functions tab on the left.

Scroll down and you will see Span Window Across all Monitors and the keyboard shortcut for it.

After you have spanned a window you can revert back by using the same shortcut.

You can change the shortcut if you want by double clicking on it.

Comment: This answer is very unclear - what is the DF taskbar?? After some research, the only plausible thing that came up was [displayfusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/), which apparently is Windows only.